# Pandas: drop_duplicates not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the following series, `drop_duplicates` is not working correctly:

```
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8670.0
8670.0
8670.0
8670.0
8670.0
8670.0
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8672.0
8670.0
8670.0
8670.0
8670.0
8670.0
```

by using `drop_duplicates(keep='first')`, it should return 4 values:

```
8672.0
8670.0
8672.0
8670.0
```

but actually, it only returns the first 2 values:

```
8672.0
8670.0
```

What's wrong with it or any suggestions for the usage of this `drop_duplicates` to get the values i want? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

[DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) removes all duplictes, not only consecutive ones.

Assuming `s` is a Series:

```
In [93]: s[s.diff().ne(0)]
Out[93]:
0     8672.0
3     8670.0
9     8672.0
19    8670.0
Name: 8672.0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you but why drop_duplicates is not behaving correctly? Or I'm using it wrongly?

Comment: OMG... guess I've been using it wrong for years... Thank you so much!

Comment: @Nathan, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think need first consecutive values, so solution is compare by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values anf filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s1 = s[s.ne(s.shift())]
print (s1)
0     8672.0
4     8670.0
10    8672.0
20    8670.0
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @Nathan - You are welcome! I think both solution are nice :)